# xpath - node test text() not working if xml document is put on one line only

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm having troubles using xpath text() function on xml documents placed on a single line. If used on the pretty-printed version of the exact same piece of xml, text() works fine.

In this case I'm using ruby and nokogiri, but I saw the same behaviour with firefox add-on [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/). I got the exact same results with both nokogiri and XPath Checker.

By the way:

Working:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse <<-EOXML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:getOSVersionResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.5">
      <return>
        <os>
          <osName>Linux</osName>
          <osVersion>2.6.18-194.26.1.el5PAE</osVersion>
          <aarNeighborhoodName/>
        </os>
      </return>
    </ns:getOSVersionResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
EOXML
```

Not working:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse <<-EOXML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:getOSVersionResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.5"><return><os><osName>Linux</osName><osVersion>2.6.18-194.26.1.el5PAE</osVersion><aarNeighborhoodName/></os></return></ns:getOSVersionResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
EOXML
```

Xpath query:

`doc.xpath("//*[not(text())]")`

My ultimate goal is to find and remove the empty xml nodes (`<aarNeighborhoodName/>` in this case).

With the pretty-printed xml I find one empty tag (this is correct):

```
> doc.xpath("//*[not(text())]")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1862238 name="aarNeighborhoodName">]
> doc.xpath("//*[not(text())]").length
=> 1
```

With xml placed on a single line I have

```
> doc.xpath("//*[not(text())]").length
=> 6
```

This is wrong because I have not six empty xml nodes.

How can I make xpath work with one-liner xml docs?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

`//*[not(text())]` will give you all the elements that do not have any immediate children that are text nodes.  When your XML is all on one line this is true of all the elements except `osName` and `osVersion` because they don't have any child text nodes, only child elements.  When the XML is pretty-printed most of your elements have text node children that consist entirely of whitespace, which is why it appears to "work" in that case.

If you want to test for elements that are completely empty, with no child nodes at all (text nodes, elements, comments, ...) then use

```
//*[not(node())]
```

Note that *attribute* nodes are not considered to be "children" in the XPath data model, so this will still pick up things like `<emptyElement with="attribute" />`.  If you want to exclude those as well then you need

```
//*[not(@*|node())]
```